# ambiguous implicit values in scala-redis connector

Tags: scala, redis, connector, sbt-assembly

I am trying to use Scala-Redis connector. Here is the code to establish connection.

```
object RedisConnection extends Serializable {
            lazy val r: RedisClient = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379,5)
         }
```

I defined the connection this way because I was getting "task not serialisable error". 
When I did `println(RedisConnection.r.get("microcin b17"))` , I got the following error, when trying to do sbt assembly

```
ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value parseString in object Implicits of type => com.redis.serialization.Parse[String]
[error]  and value parseByteArray in object Implicits of type => com.redis.serialization.Parse[Array[Byte]]
[error]  match expected type com.redis.serialization.Parse[A]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried specifying exactly the type you want?
r.get[String]("microcin b17")

Comment: Thanks. That seems to work.

Comment: OK, I'll post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specifying exactly the type you want

```
r.get[String]("microcin b17")
```